# To what קולות does "אדם חשוב שאני" apply (שבת נא ע״א)?

Tags: maseches-shabbos, leniencies

[*Bavli*, *Shabas* 51 *amud* 1](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=224), in my own loose translation:

> *R. Nachman* said to his servant *Daru*: "Insulate some cold water for me, and bring me water that a non-Jewish cook has heated."
>
> *R. Ami* heard and got upset.
>
> *R. Yosef* asked why he had gotten upset. [After all, *R. Nachman*] had acted in accordance with his teachers: one [statement] like *Rav* and one like *Sh'muel*. Like *Sh'muel*, as *R. Y'huda* said *Sh'muel* had said one may insulate cold water; and like *Rav*, as *R. Sh'muel b. R. Yitzchak* said *Rav* had said anything eaten as-is, raw, has no issue of gentile's-cooking.
>
> [The answer is: *R. Ami*] holds an important person is different.

*Rashi* explains the last line:

> An important person is different: for someone who sees him being lenient will proceed to be even more lenient.

To what leniencies or types of leniencies does this latter concern apply? Just as one example, one is allowed to set up a site outside his city on *Shabas* to serve as his "base" for *Shabas* (*eruv t'chumin*). Would *R. Ami* say an important person cannot? But that's just an example: I seek to know what *R. Ami*'s statement's parameters are in general.

Comment: E.g. Adam Chosuv - if he's lost in unending water, his wife may be allowed to remarry, as per yesterday's Daf (2nd last in Yavomos)

Comment: @DannySchoemann You are talking about R' Ashi's opinion regarding צורבא מרבנן (since news would spread if a scholar survived), which the gemara rejects. You are correct, though, that there are some leniencies for an אדם חשוב. For example, the *Shulchan Aruch* (OC 275:4, based on Rava's ruling in *Shabbos* 12b) rules than an אדם חשוב who knows that he does not have a habit of tilting his lamp even during the week may read from a lamp on Shabbos. Although, the *Mishna B'rura* (s"k 12) does not rule accordingly, he does indicate that this, combined with use of wax candles, would be a סניף להקל.

Comment: There are different views about this. For example, the באר שבע (shu"t §48) suggests that this principle might not extend beyond the realm of בישול עכו"ם. However, there are gemaras that seem to suggest that it could (e.g. Abaye and Rava being strict about *muktza* in *Shabbos* 142b, Rav Safra and Rav Huna bar Chin'na avoided a scholar's palace that was built by non-Jewish contractors on Shabbos outside of the *t'chum* in *Mo'ed Kattan* 12a, R' Ami being upset with R' Y'huda N'si'a for wearing a signet ring in a *chatzer* on Shabbos in M"K 12b, etc.).

Comment: Also, there are other understandings of why אדם חשוב שאני. For example, the *M'iri* (M"K 12a) says "אדם חשוב ראוי לקדש עצמו אף במותר לו ". And the *Shita M'kubetzes* (*K'subos* 86a) suggests that the issue is חשד.

Comment: I originally read the title as *kolot*, sounds, instead of *kulot*, leniencies.